# How to extract number of interest from an array while comparing it with a different array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following two arrays:

```py
array([154, 390, 635, 881], dtype=int64)

array([ 19,  25,  55,  95,  96, 100, 104, 125, 177, 191, 193, 209, 211,
        215, 217, 220, 260, 262, 264, 268, 299, 371, 418, 454, 457, 460,
        464, 467, 474, 476, 502, 504, 506, 511, 544, 615, 661, 707, 746,
        748, 752, 757, 787, 853, 855, 856, 906, 945, 989, 998], dtype=int64)
```

I want a code that will create a third array or list that will contain values from the second array that are the first number that is larger than the values of the first i.e. 177, 418, 661 and 906.

I tried the following code:

```
for i in range(len(xi)):
    newlist =[]
    for j in range(len(peaks)):
        if xi[i] > peaks[j] : newlist.append(xi[i])
        j=j+1
```

but the answer is `[998, 998, 998, 998]` which is the largest number of the second array

what i should change in order to have the desired values?

Thank you

Comment: Bare in mind that if your arrays are big, you will hugely benefit from using numpy, and avoiding loops. Also, why go with a python based solution, having numpy arrays?

Comment: THank you for the info! I have that in mind but for the purpose of my work i need a loop that can easily be translated in another languages like C, C++ etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [154, 390, 635, 881]

b = [ 19,  25,  55,  95,  96, 100, 104, 125, 177, 191, 193, 209, 211,
        215, 217, 220, 260, 262, 264, 268, 299, 371, 418, 454, 457, 460,
        464, 467, 474, 476, 502, 504, 506, 511, 544, 615, 661, 707, 746,
        748, 752, 757, 787, 853, 855, 856, 906, 945, 989, 998]

new = []
for n in a:
    for m in b:
        if m > n:
            new.append(m)
            break
print(new)
```

You need to break out of the second loop whenever you found the first number greater than the number you are comparing from the first array

Comment: Thank you dzang! I really appreciate the comment about why my code was working!

Answer (score 2):

We can use broadcasting to compare both arrays, and take the `argmax` along the second axis to find the indices of the first `True` values. Then index `b` with the resulting integer index array:

```
b[(b > a[:,None]).argmax(1)]
# array([177, 418, 661, 906])
```

---

Setup -

```
a = np.array([154, 390, 635, 881])

b = np.array([ 19,  25,  55,  95,  96, 100, 104, 125, 177, 191, 193, 209, 211,
        215, 217, 220, 260, 262, 264, 268, 299, 371, 418, 454, 457, 460,
        464, 467, 474, 476, 502, 504, 506, 511, 544, 615, 661, 707, 746,
        748, 752, 757, 787, 853, 855, 856, 906, 945, 989, 998])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help yatu! I didn't know the broadcasting of numpy arrays. I will look further into it :) !

Answer (score 1):

This approach looks for the minimum value in the `a2` array which is greater than each element in the `a1` array; then appends each minimum value to a list of results.

#### Data:

```
a1 = np.array([154, 390, 635, 881)

a2 = np.array([19,  25,  55,  95,  96, 100, 104, 125, 177, 191, 193, 209, 211,
               215, 217, 220, 260, 262, 264, 268, 299, 371, 418, 454, 457, 460,
               464, 467, 474, 476, 502, 504, 506, 511, 544, 615, 661, 707, 746,
               748, 752, 757, 787, 853, 855, 856, 906, 945, 989, 998])
```

#### Sample Code:

```
l = []
for i in range(a1.size):
    l.append(a2[a2>a1[i]].min())
```

#### Output:

```
[177, 418, 661, 906]
```

Comment: Thank you S3DEV, i really appreciate the answer. I don' have a good graps of the python syntax yet but i am getting there! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using numpy arrays, you can use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) if array `b` is sorted

```
a = np.array([154, 390, 635, 881], dtype=int64)    
b = np.array([ 19,  25,  55,  95,  96, 100, 104, 125, 177, 191, 193, 209, 211,
        215, 217, 220, 260, 262, 264, 268, 299, 371, 418, 454, 457, 460,
        464, 467, 474, 476, 502, 504, 506, 511, 544, 615, 661, 707, 746,
        748, 752, 757, 787, 853, 855, 856, 906, 945, 989, 998], dtype=int64)

b[np.searchsorted(b,a, side='right')]
```

Output

```
array([177, 418, 661, 906])
```

- to search for `>` use the argument `side='right'`
- to search for `>=` use the argument `side='left'`, which is the default behaviour.

---

### Micro-Benchmark

Comparing searching with [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007605/14277722) and `numpy.searchsorted`

[image: benchmark results]

Code for the benchmark

```
def broadcast(n):
    b,a = n
    b.sort()
    return b[(b > a[:,None]).argmax(1)]
def searchsort(n):
    b,a = n
    b.sort()
    return b[np.searchsorted(b,a, side='right')]

import perfplot
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (np.random.randint(1, n, n), np.random.randint(1, n, n // 10)),
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(5,18)],
    kernels=[broadcast, searchsort],
    xlabel="len(x)",
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the details and the alternatives mikksu! It is really help me learn more about python and the efficiency chart is very useful! :)